# how to initialize string pointer?

Tags: c++, string

I want to store the static value in string pointer is it posible?

If I do like

```
string *array = {"value"};
```

the error occurs

```
error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'std::string*' in initialization
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you would then need to write

```
string *array = new string("value");
```

although you are better off using

```
string array = "value";
```

as that is the intended way to use it. otherwise you need to keep track of memory.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::string` pointer has to point to an `std::string` object. What it actually points to depends on your use case. For example:

```
std::string s("value"); // initialize a string
std::string* p = &s; // p points to s
```

In the above example, `p` points to a local `string` with automatic storage duration. When it it gets destroyed, anything that points to it will point to garbage.

You can also make the pointer point to a dynamically allocated string, in which case you are in charge of releasing the resources when you are done:

```
std::string* p = new std::string("value"); // p points to dynamically allocated string
// ....
delete p; // release resources when done
```

You would be advised to use [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointers) instead of raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects.

Answer (score 1):

As `array` is an array of `string`s you could try this:

```
int main()
{
  string *array = new string[1]; 
  array[1] = "value";
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly convert the literal to a string:

```
 std::string array[] = {std::string("value")};
```

Note that you have to define this as an array, not a pointer though. Of course, an array mostly makes sense if you have more than one element, like:

```
string array[] = {string("value1"), string("value2"), string("etc")};
```