# Initializing strings using pointers

Tags: c, string

What is the difference between:

```
char arr[20]="I am a string"
```

and

```
char *arr="I am a string"
```

How is it possible to initialize an array just by using a pointer?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to initialize string pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859737/how-to-initialize-string-pointer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char s\[\] and char \*s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is in allocated storage size. First expression allocates 20 chars, but the second expression allocate the length of the string (13 chars).

The second difference is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164258/3768871). which is discussed on the way how these variables are allocated.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how the string is initialized to a pointer in second method since pointers are used to point another variable

Answer (score 2):

First one is clear, it is an array initialisation, whereas the second one means that character pointer *arr is pointing to the unnamed static array which will store the String " I am a string".

Answer (score 1):

In first case you are partially initializing stack allocated array with 14 chars taken from buffer represented by `"I am a string"` string literal.

In second case you are initializing stack allocated pointer with a pointer to a buffer with static storage duration represented by `"I am a string"` string literal. Also notice that in second case you should use `const char *arr`.